# Android SqLite no such column _id exception

Tags: android, sqlite

Don't immediately flag me for a duplicate question. My issue is different because I have a correctly formatted SQL query.

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "log";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String LOG_TEXT = "logtext";
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        LOG_TEXT + " TEXT not null);";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);

}
```

and I query here

```
String[] columns = {LOG_TEXT,COLUMN_ID};
    Cursor cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, COLUMN_ID + " desc");
```

and I catch this the exception generated containing the sql query.

```
catch(Exception e){
Log.D("sql Exception",e.getMessage());}
```

and it returns

```
no such column: _id: , while compiling: SELECT logtext, _id FROM log ORDER BY _id desc
```

I'm familar with Oracle SQL and relational databases in general. Is it my ORDER BY clause? I was certain you can ALWAYS use order by. It doesn't have the same behavior as GROUP BY.

Any ideas on why the exception?
Incase anyone wants to see i'm updating with my ArrayAdaptor statements. I'm using the cursor in a listview

```
String[] data = query();


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Rewrite**

Whenever you change the schema in `TABLE_CREATE` you must inform you app of these changes, they will not happen automatically when you change `TABLE_CREATE`. The easiest way to do this is to increment your `database_version` in your extended SQLiteOpenHelper class. You discovered you can also uninstall / reinstall the app, for the same results. If you are savvy with SQL you could ALTER the table.  But whatever the method you must make sure that you app makes the schema changes before trying to access the new columns...

Also for SQLite:

```
_id integer primary key
```

is [synonymous](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) with:

```
_id integer primary key autoincrement not null
```

And queries use descending as the default order, so `ORDER BY _id` is the same as `ORDER BY _id DESC`.

Comment: Is this because of ORDER BY behavior when I'm trying to sort? Never ran into this before.

Comment: I am guessing that you are binding this query with a ListView, Spinner, etc these require `_id` as the first column otherwise it will throw the exception that you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i had the ListView working before I tried to ORDER BY _id. There were no problems with that. And switching the order of COLUMN_ID and LOG_TEXT did not work.

Comment: I just tested this myself and you are correct `_id` does not have to be the first column, however I can use `_id` in my ORDER BY without a problem... Have you changed `TABLE_CREATE`? If so you need to drop and recreate the database, the easiest way is to this is increment the database version.

Comment: I'm going to try uninstalling the app on my test device. That should wipe the database.

Comment: Uninstalling it worked..somehow. So the schema must not have been what I assumed.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, meaning it should have worked but didn't (had some typos in the create command that I fixed but that still didn't help). A colleague then told me to try clearing the data (just at AppInfo and then "Clear Data") which solved my problem, apparently the old database (that didn't work) was still there and had to be cleared out first.

I just put this answer here in case anybody else like me (android beginner) stumbles across this problem, because I went through dozens of stackoverflow threads with this problem but not one offered this possibility/solution and it bothered me for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the definition of the `_id` column to your create statement later on, i.e. after the code had already been run once?  Databases are persisted files, so if you modify the table structure in your code you need to make sure you clear your application's data so the database file can ge re-created with the correct table/column data.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused. But I beleive I included the code where I create the table.

Comment: Yes but the question is, was that always the code you used to create the table, or have you run your application in the past with a create statement that did not include the `_id` column.  `onCreate()` only gets called if the database file does not already exist, otherwise the application opens the existing file, which may have an old structure in it if you changed the code.

Comment: No, this is the only place where I create the database. I understand they are persistent and after creating it I execute simple inserts and queries. No modifications to the schema. Appreciate the reply